# npm install highcharts-export server filename problem

Tags: highcharts

```
            filename: "Verimlilik Göstergeleri",
            enabled: true,
            sourceWidth: 1024,
            sourceHeight: 768,
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: [
                        // "viewFullscreen",
                        "printChart",
                        "separator",
                        "downloadPNG",
                        "downloadJPEG",
                        "downloadPDF",
                        "downloadSVG"
                    ],
                    symbol: "menu"
                }
            },
```

The letter ö is deduced as ı. I need your help, can you please help?

Thank you,

Comment: Hi, I've created a simple config for exporting: https://jsfiddle.net/0kx5vm9u/ and tested it out on both our deployed Export Server and my local one (the latest version) and everything seems to work as expected. The exported filenames are correct.

Could you please share the reproduction steps? What kind of export are you performing and how? Which version of the Export Server are you using?

Comment: Hi Jakup,   "highcharts": "8.0.4",
  "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
  "highcharts-exporting": "^0.1.7",
  "highcharts-rounded-corners": "^1.0.6",

Answer (score 0):

The `highcharts-exporting` package you're using has been published 6+ years and is deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-exporting

If you import `highcharts` and our officially supported `exporting.js` module, everything will work as expected.

Here's a **demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/0kx5vm9u/

If you're using Angular and [`highcharts-angular`](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular), you can just import the exporting modul. It is well explained in the `highcharts-angular` documentation: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular?tab=readme-ov-file#to-load-a-module

I've tested the problem you described with our latest version of Highcharts and our official Export Server solution and everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: Hi Jakub, unfortunately both methods did not work.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue in an online code editor like JSFiddle or CodeSandbox?